# Android Marshmallow dlopen failed "libxyz.so" not found

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, dlopen

My app requires, Microphone access to record audio. App also uses some native libraries. The app is working fine for targetSdkVersion set to less than or equal to 22. I want to run my app on Android Marshmallow. 
I get following error on Android M:

> dlopen failed: library "libxyz.so" not found

Following steps lead to error:

1. Launch app. App asks for Microphone permissions. Grant permission
2. Go to Device Settings & revoke microphone permission (App restarts
   on Android M)
3. Now re-grant Microphone access to the app.
4. Go to app. When I try to capture audio now, I hit the dlopen error.

On the other hand though, if I launch app, grant permissions & capture audio everything works fine. Issue seems to be with revoking/re-granting permissions(steps 2-3-4 above). If I only do step 1 above, android is able to load the native library & everything works seamlessly. This clearly confirms that, there is no issue with packaging & libs are available.

I have already read this: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html

My native lib doesnt have "**text relocations**"(they are built with fPIC flag). Moreover when dlopen() fails, dlerror() is **NULL**, which is not very helpful.I also used "**eu-findtextrel**" utility to confirm none of my native libs have "**text relocations**"

I have also read these posts: [Android M crash java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845956/android-m-crash-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dlopen-failed)

[Unable to dlopen(libsomething.so) Cannot load library: link_image[1995]: failed to link libsomething.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723681/unable-to-dlopenlibsomething-so-cannot-load-library-link-image1995-failed)

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92473/dlopen-failed-library-system-lib-libhoudini-so-not-found

Since none of the above have helped me, I am posting my query. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Hey Ganesh, did you get to the root cause of this issue?